# Stripe trigger - reporting.report_run.failed not supported by Stripe CLI - alternative way to force a 'failed' report_run webhook event

Tags: stripe-payments, command-line-interface

I am using the Stripe CLI and have setup the Stripe listener in my terminal - I would like to be able to use the Strigger trigger command to trigger a `reporting.report_run.failed` webhook event.

When I run this - I am informed that the CLI doesn't support -
https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-reporting.report_run.failed

```
stripe trigger reporting.report_run.failed 
The event 'reporting.report_run.failed' is not supported by the Stripe CLI.
```

Annoyingly you can use `stripe trigger reporting.report_run.succeeded` so it is just the `failed` report run that isn't supported by the CLI.

Is there any other way to 'force' this `reporting.report_run.failed` webhook event? I am surprised that it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

`stripe trigger` can only run fixtures defined in [this file](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/tree/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers). You can add your own fixtures, but I am not sure how you would simulate a report failing to run. I assume that's the reason why this fixture wasn't added in the first place. Therefore I don't think it's possible to simulate this event, unfortunately.

Comment: yeah I presumed that to be the case - just odd as I am not sure how to simulate a failed report run